# Page not found error for html file used in jsp project

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am learning Jsp and  working on a basic Jsp project which is using a HTML file in it. 
When I run the HTML file, it gives page not found error and while running the Jsp, it does not load the form and button in it. 
Kindly help me out.

Below are my HTML and Jsp files:

Index.html

```
<html>
<head><title>New</title></head>
<body>
<form action="myFirstJsp.jsp">
<input type="text" name="uname">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

myFirstJsp.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My First JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<%String name= request.getParameter("uname");
out.println("Welcome " +name);%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deployed your project on server?

Comment: This question has many answers. Provide more information like whether the project is deployed nor not, project structure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your server is up & your app is well deployed on it. Check the request url being fired from the browser.
Also

It's a good practice to use jstl  tag to provide urls in your application. It computes the context path averting 404 page not found errors due to incorrect urls.

```
<form action="<c:url value="/myFirstJsp.jsp">
```

Add the jstl library in your jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"/>
```